# Pointer Question

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Can you please explain to me what is happening here?

```
char data[128]; // Create char array of size 128.
long * ptr;     // Create a pointer.
ptr = (long *) data;   // ??
```

Mainly, what does the (long *) mean?

Does it mean that the data is of type char, and I am casting the reference to data as a reference to a long?

Thank you.

Comment: Flagged for already being answered a hundred times over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is casting the data pointer as a pointer to a long.

The line:

```
 char data[128];
```

will allocate 128 bytes of memory and treat that data as characters.  The code:

```
 long * ptr;
 ptr = (long *) data;
```

allocates a pointer to a long, and sets that pointer to point at the memory allocated by `char data[128];`.

You can reference this memory by `data[x]` to get the xth character starting at the beginning of this memory block.  Or you can reference this memory by `ptr[x]` to get the xth long starting at the beginning of this memory block.  Just note that each long takes up more storage than each character.  It is probably 8 bytes - so you can go up to `data[127]` or `ptr[15]`.

Answer (score 3):

The `(long*)` expression is a C style cast.  It treates the memory pointed to by `data` and treats it as a pointer to data of type `long`

Answer (score 1):

It is a "C-style" cast; in your case, it translates into a "reinterpret cast". Read it as "take a pointer to a `char` type, and treat it as if it pointed to `long`". The preferred way to write it is `reinterpret_cast<long>(ptr)`. Note that valid indexes are from 0 to `128 * sizeof(char) / sizeof(long) - 1`, which may differ between platforms.

Answer (score 0):

`(long *)` is a typecast.  Since `data` is an array of `char`, this typecast is needed to make the assignment to `ptr`, which is a `long *` pointer.  Your "does it mean" sentence is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This statement means, take data (which is the memory address of the start of 128 chars), and treat that memory address instead as the start of a long number.

This seems very risky and foolish.

Is there any particular reason this is being done?

Answer (score 0):

`(long *)` is a cast. It tells the compiler "this here `char[128]` you've got? Treat it as a `long *`." But then you assign that to a `char *` pointer, which a) is an invalid assignment without a cast from `long *` to `char *`, and b) won't preserve the... longitude... of the variable.

Basically, it's pointless in this particular example. I suspect it's because you've modified the original code for display here--can you show us what it actually looks like?